# Why is the virtual machine unable to access the external network when starting in qemu bridge mode

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, bridge

I have just started using QEMU and encountered some issues. The specific situation is as follows：
Host ifconfig：

```
br0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.4.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.4.255
        inet6 fe80::c475:70ff:fe1b:fed3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:83:ad:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 599  bytes 60048 (60.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 623  bytes 91375 (91.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:d0ff:fea3:3ac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:d0:a3:03:ac  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 207  bytes 15690 (15.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49  bytes 7030 (7.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:83:ad:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 150666  bytes 40910039 (40.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 159170  bytes 33851183 (33.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6922  bytes 551196 (551.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6922  bytes 551196 (551.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The host is a cloud server and does not support kvm.
br0 is a bridge, eth0 is the host network card.

Command to start VM: `sudo /opt/qemu-6.2.0/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name normal-vm -m 2G -hda focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=./OVMF.fd,readonly=on -nographic -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0 -netdev bridge,id=hostnet0,br=br0,helper=/opt/qemu-6.2.0/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper`

After logging in to the VM: executing dhclient command stuck, unable to obtain IP. After setting the static IP address through netplan, the external network(eg: ping google.com) is still inaccessible.

cat /etc/netplan/a.yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses: [10.0.4.17/24] 
      gateway4: 10.0.4.1
      #gateway4: 10.0.4.16
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,114.114.114.114]
      optional: true
```

gateway4 has tried 10.0.4.1 and 10.0.4.16.

VM ifconfig(static IP):

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.4.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.4.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:56  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17  bytes 981 (981.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 5559 (5.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 246  bytes 18794 (18.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 246  bytes 18794 (18.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

At this time, it is still unable to ping the external network.

I'm not sure where the problem is and how to solve it.
I hope that after starting the virtual machine through the bridge mode, the virtual machine can communicate with the external network.
May I ask how I can achieve this through QEMU?